# How can I script a python code to install MiKTeX, Strawberry Perl and some Python packages?

Tags: python, perl, executable, miktex

I created a python script to generate a document. I want other people to use it without having a hurdle to install all the necessary software and packages. So, I was wondering how I could generate an executable python code to install MiKTeX, Strawberry Perl and some Python packages.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/) to create a executable for python and the including python packages. To install MiKTeX I would write a bat file which leads you throw the installation and select packages from MiKTeX are on the fly installed.